# Selecting only Non-file Parameters from Laravel Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For one of my Laravel Web app I want to log all the Request Parameters(Post as well as Get) in database in **Json Format** for that I am using `$request->all()` Method, which results in an exception when user tries to upload any file.

that's why I want a way to select only Serializable Parameters from the request.(for get as well as for post Requests) or a way to select all the request parameters except files.

`Request::except([])` will not work for me since in Except method we will have to provide the file parameter names.

Comment: When the parameters are known you can use $request->except(['file_field_name']); Was a bit too fast for your edit.

Comment: but all the parameters are not known to me so I can't use `except` method... @TimvanUum

Comment: Your best Option there is to loop through the $request->all()... then make a control flow that would exempt input with (dot)  extension...

Comment: Why vote down???, Downvoters please comment why are you voting down any Question or Answer???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any of the answer didn't work for me I did lots of reading and some digging about laravel but still I could not find the specific solutions I was looking for, so I did a small hack, instead of using Laravel's Request Object and pulling parameters from there I simply used PHP's built in `$_REQUEST` parameter.

Eg.

`$non_file_parameters = $_REQUEST;`

`$_REQUEST` will have both Get as well as Post Parameters except file Parameters coz in Core PHP for files we have `$_FILES` super global variable.

Thanks guys for your efforts...

Answer (score 3):

In my project, i used this except for many fields like below,

```
 $input = $request->except('first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'address',...);
```

It is work fine for me.
  I stored all the remain values into **$input** and store values from that input variable.

Please try this one.

Answer (score 2):

In your case please take this debug code for test once, might be you like it to use in your current work

```
$allRequestParams = array_map(function($input) {
        return !is_array($input) ? $input : false;
    }, $request->all());
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($allRequestParams);
    echo '<pre/>';
    die;
```